# Microsoft Graph: failure when filtering 'oauth2PermissionScopes' array using lambda operators

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In Microsoft Graph Explorer, I am trying to use the following GET query with a lambda filter to find any/all servicePrincipals (such as "Microsoft Graph", etc) which expose delegated permissions matching a specific display name. This query returns one of the following errors. What is the root cause, and is there a way to make my query succeed?

**Query:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/<verson>/servicePrincipals?$filter=oauth2PermissionScopes/any(x:x/userConsentDisplayName+eq+'read+files')&$count=true
```

**Error Messages:**

- When using the v1.0 Graph endpoint: "Unsupported query."
- When using the beta Graph endpoint: "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'oauth2PermissionScopes' of resource 'ServicePrincipal'."

For reference, servicePrincipals data is returned in the following structure:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals",
    "@odata.nextLink": "url in here",
    "value": [
        {
            "appId": "00000000-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-000000000000",
            "displayName": "Some Application Name",
            <...snip...>
            "oauth2PermissionScopes": [
                {
                    <...snip...>
                    "userConsentDisplayName": "read files",
                    "value": "Files.ReadWrite"
                }
            ],
            "someOtherField": "someOtherValue"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Tried:**

- I am submitting my API request with the "ConsistencyLevel" header set to "eventual", as I've read elsewhere that sometimes this setting is needed.
- Despite searching official documentation, I have been unable to determine whether oauth2PermissionScopes is even filter-able in the first place, so this query attempt might be futile.

**Expected:**
I *assume* that oauth2PermissionScopes is filter-able, so I would expect the query to succeed, even if my exact query does not give me the data I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid we can't add filter on `oauth2PermissionScopes`, here's my test result.

[image]

So I go to the document of `servicePrincipals` properties and found property which is supported filter has a tip mentions it, but `oauth2PermissionScopes` doesn't have it. So I'm afraid we can't do it via current version.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suspect that you are correct in your assessment that filtering on `oauth2PermissionScopes` isn't currently possible. FYI, the 400 error in your screenshot can be avoided by enabling/setting the "ConsistencyLevel" header set to "eventual". However, even then, you will then see the same error messages that I mentioned in the original question :(

Comment: yes, I reproduced your error first in my side and try to troubleshoot, but after removing the `$count` I saw the error message which seems to mean this property is not supported to filter.... thank you for your kind reply : )